# Streaming video from C# server to wowza streaming engine

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, streaming, wowza

I'm facing problem with restreaming .h264 video received from my device via tcp to wowza streaming engine. The problem is that I do not know how to forward byte array (byte[]). I have read that it is possible via rstp/rtmp/mpegts but I have not found any library to do this operation. I know that video I receive is ok because after saving frames to file I'm able to send it to wowza using ffmpeg. I have been also trying to use ffmpeg to listen on udp ip and port and on http ip and port but nothing happened.

---

My question is: 
Is it possible to send bytes to ffmpeg without saving file on hard drive?

Comment: I just have googled my own question looking for an answer :c